# How Do I Add Months to a ts object plot?

Tags: r, time-series

I have a monthly time series as so:

```
test <- rnorm(23, mean = 10, sd = 1)
test <- ts(test,start=c(2018,6), frequency = 12)
```

My starting plot looks like so:

```
gg <- autoplot(test)
gg
```

How do I add to the plot so that the x axis has tick marks for each month?

As well, how can I have the months displayed vertically rather than horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not use the `ts` object, but using the `month` function in `lubridate` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
```

Create artificial data on some price, at a daily frequency, with the time-index named as *tmd*:

```
set.seed(97531)
tmd <- seq(as.Date("2019/1/1"), as.Date("2019/12/31"), by = "day")
price <- rnorm(length(tmd), mean = 1000, sd=200)
price <- cbind.data.frame(tmd, price)
```

Extract the month  information:

```
price$Month <- lubridate::month(tmd, label = T)
```

Create a summary data set of average prices:

```
    avg.price <- price %>% group_by(Month) %>% 
  summarise("Average Price" = mean(price))
```

Plot

```
ggplot()+geom_line(data = avg.price, aes(x=Month, y = `Average Price`, group=1))+
theme_bw()+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Lazy solution

Convert `"ts"` to `"xts"` and plot it.

```
library(xts)
test.xts <- as.xts(test.ts)

plot(test.xts)
```

[image]

We have monthly tick marks, there are gaps between the labels though. We could do `plot(test.xts, las=2)` for 90° rotation, labels are plotted beyond margins though, and it seems impossible to use `par(mar=)` with `plot.xtx`.

## Exact solution

The time information of `"ts"` objects is stored in an `attr`ibute named `"tsp"` with the values start, end, and frequency. The former two are stored as decimal years, the latter as an integer. The number of tick marks equals the `length` of your `test.ts` object.

```
ydc <- attr(test.ts, "tsp")[1]  ## start as decimal year
frq <- attr(test.ts, "tsp")[3]  ## frequency
## extract start date
start. <- c(floor(ydc), round((ydc - floor(ydc))*frq + 1), 1)
start.date <- as.Date(do.call(ISOdate, as.list(c(start., 1))))
date.seq <-  ## generate date sequence
  format(seq(start.date, length.out=length., by="month"), "%Y.%m")
length. <- length(test.ts)  ## number of tick marks
```

Using this information we may `plot` your `test.ts` by `unclass`ing it in order to get the `axTicks` as integers rather than as decimal years. We use `xaxt="n"` to suppress axis ticks and generate them manually using `axis` and `mtext`. In the latter we set `las=2` to rotate them 90°.

```
op <- par(mar=c(8, 5, 5, 4))  ## expanding plot margins a little
plot(unclass(test.ts), xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="values", type="l", main="My Title")
axis(1, seq.default(date.seq), labels=F)  ## tick marks
mtext(date.seq, 1, 1, at=seq.default(date.seq), las=2, cex=.8)  ## tick labels
mtext("time", 1, 4.5)  ## x axis label
## grid
abline(v=seq(test.ts), lty=3, col="gray80")
abline(h=axTicks(2), lty=3, col="gray80")
par(op)  ## restore default margins
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
test.ts <- structure(c(11.3709584471467, 9.43530182860391, 10.3631284113373, 
10.632862604961, 10.404268323141, 9.89387548390852, 11.5115219974389, 
9.9053409615869, 12.018423713877, 9.93728590094758, 11.3048696542235, 
12.2866453927011, 8.61113929888766, 9.72121123318263, 9.86667866360634, 
10.6359503980701, 9.71574707858393, 7.34354457909522, 7.55953307142448, 
11.3201133457302, 9.69336140592153, 8.21869156602, 9.82808264424038
), .Tsp = c(2018.41666666667, 2020.25, 12), class = "ts")
```

Comment: Sorry - I should have included this: Is there a way to do this with ggplot?